# How can I embed inline styling on a page using an existing css file as a source data?

Tags: html, css

Assuming i have a css file called inline.css which contains some css,
how can i inline this css into the markup ?
I want it to be inlined to the markup, NOT included as an external css resourcs .
so assuming my slim markup is:

```
<html><head>
<!-- code to make the style inlined here ... -->
</head>
<body>hello</body></html>
```

and assuming my inline.css is:

```
body { background-color: green; }
```

i want the final output markup to be:

```
<html><head>
<style>
body { background-color: green; }
</style>
<body>
hello
</body>
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using Slim. That's just standard HTML.

Comment: your remark does not matter for the sake of this question

Comment: It matters for whether or not I'm going to edit your question to remove the `slim-lang` tag, if your question doesn't actually have anything to do with Slim

Comment: you can edit the question to make it slim

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check these docs out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This would have to be done server-side, so what server technology are you using?

Comment: 1st: this is not called inline styling that is called using Internal style sheet
2nd: the result of using an external stylesheet is exactly the same

Comment: could you please elaborate more what is the reason you want to do that

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you are trying, but it is possible if you are using server side rendering. Read CSS file and render it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            <%= Data from css file here %>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

but remember, including CSS into your HTML increases file size. Also you can't cache stylesheets if you are using inline styles. Please reconsider what you are trying to do.